# Can I build a SSIS 2008 custom component using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, components

I have built custom components for SSIS 2008 using VS2008. Can I build a custom component for SSIS 2008 using VS2010?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes.

Yes, you can build SSIS 2008 custom components using *Visual Studio 2010* but you need to target **`.NET Framework 3.5`** because SSIS 2008 does not support *`.NET Framework 4.0`*

#### Reference:

You can take a look at this answer on MSDN forum that discusses a similar question.

[*SSIS Custom Components and .NET 4.0*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/73b1a2af-d35b-4cdf-81b2-a1020ffbc696)